# Sending output from child process to parent using pipe (redirecting stdout to pipe) using Boost C++

Tags: c++, boost, blocking, nonblocking

I am new to Boost library. I am trying to spawn a child process using `bp::child c()` and redirecting the stdout to a pipe/stream. The problem that I am facing is, converting that stream to a string requires the use of `getline`, which is blocking. As such, creating the child process and executing it is non-blocking, as mentioned in the documentation. But since getline is blocking, the code after getline has to wait until the child process has completed execution.

Is there a non-blocking alternative to getline ? Or should I be trying a different way to communicate the output of child process to parent ? Here is the sample code for reference :

```
bp::ipstream p;
bp::child c(cmd, bp::std_out > p);
std::string line;
std::getline(p, line)
std::cout<<line;

//doSomething();

c.wait();
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is no. Boost also provided the `asio` library implementing asynchronous I/O. You can try with it
Here is an example for reference

```
boost::asio::io_service ios; 
std::vector<char> buf(4096);    
bp::async_pipe ap(ios);    
bp::child c(cmd, bp::std_out > boost::asio::buffer(buf), ios);
//Do something
ios.run();
std::string s(buf.begin(), buf.end());
std::cout << s;
c.wait();
```